# Codeigniter blog application: replace post id with slug in the singe post url only

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

I have been working for some time on this application and consequently, it has a lot of features. Most of these rely on the ids of posts, pages, etc.

For SEO purposes, I would like to use friendly URLs, instead of ids to display the *individual posts*, so I have added a `slug` column to the `posts` table.

[image]

The slugs are made from post titles, with this chunks of code in the *Posts_model* model and the *Posts* controller, respectively.

From the **model**:

```
public function slug_count($slug){
    $this->db->select('count(*) as slugcount');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row(0)->slugcount;
}

public function create_post($post_image, $slug) {
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'post_image' => $post_image,
        'author_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'cat_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
    return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
}
```

From the **controller**:

```
// Create slug (from title)
$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
$slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
if ($slugcount > 0) {
    $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
}
```

To achieve my SEO goal, I have considered and tried out the approach in **[this tutorial](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/codeigniter-simple-mvc-crud-add-edit-delete-view/)** but since there are numerous functionalities needing ids (deleting posts via AJAX, for example) and other that do not *require* slugs (editing posts) I am unable (and unwilling) to substantially modify the post viewing method in the controller,

```
public function post($id) {
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->sidebar_posts($limit=5, $offset=5);
    $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);

    if ($data['categories']) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
            $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
        }
    }

    if (!empty($data['post'])) {
        // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
        $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;

        // Get post comments
        $post_id = $data['post']->id;
        $data['comments'] = $this->Comments_model->get_comments($post_id);

        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('post');
    } else {
        $data['tagline'] = "Page not found";
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('404');
    }
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}
```

and the corresponding code in the model:

```
public function get_post($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('id' => $id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->row();
        // run separate query for author name
        $author_query = $this->db->get_where('authors', array('id' => $data->author_id));
        if ($author_query->num_rows() == 1) {
            $author = $author_query->row();
            $data->first_name = $author->first_name;
            $data->last_name = $author->last_name;             
        } else {
            $data->first_name = 'Unknown';
            $data->last_name = '';
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

What would be a simple, less "intrusive" approach to replace post id with slug in the *singe post* view *only*?

Comment: So what you want to do is to have it so that post/123 and post/some-post (where Id is 123) give you the same result right? I did this when I moved to slugs ... If the URL parameter is numeric I simply search for the Id otherwise the slug and get the posts that way

Comment: Yes. How should I acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update in model**

replace

```
public function get_post($id) {
   $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('id' => $id));
```

with

```
public function get_post($slug) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
```

**Update in Controller**

replace

```
public function post($id) {
```

with

```
public function post($slug) {
```

and replace

```
$data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);
```

with

```
$data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($slug);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also update your routes for better user friendly url.

```
//If you categorize your blog
$route['blog-category/(:any)'] = 'blogController/blogFunction/$1';
//this will accept any uri
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'blogController/blogFunction'
```

Comment: I have my post at `http://localhost/ciblog/posts/post/the-post-slug`. What must I add in the routes to have `http://localhost/ciblog/the-post-slug` insead?

Comment: put like this. `$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'posts/post/$1`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can have both the id and the slug on the same function/url eg `/id/slug`. This way, you always have your `id` and seo is happy too because the url has the page title(slug). Then on your function, you can have `public function post($id,$slug="") {`.

Comment: it may not always good practice, suppose the slug actually contains a number (product id or serial number), and another id present in url, that is bad for SEO.

Comment: How would you do that? What would be an optimal way?